# ASP.NET Dropdown Count always returns 0

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my asp.net page, I have Ajax method which makes call to API controller and gets value when user clicks the dropdownbox based on other condition. This helps to avoid page refresh.

**ASP.NET Page Code**

```
<script> 
    $('#<%= ddOtherLocation.ClientID %>').click(function (e) {                
        var postData = {
            deptid: $('#<%= ddLocation.ClientID %>').val()                         
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: 'path/GetEmployeeDept',
            data: postData,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (Result) {
                $('#<%= ddOtherLocation.ClientID %>').empty();
                $('#<%= ddOtherAdLocation.ClientID %>').append($("<option value=0>Select</option>"));
                $.each(Result, function (key, value) {
                    $('#<%= ddOtherLocation.ClientID %>').append($("<option></option>").val(value.DeptID).html(value.DeptName));
                });
            },
            error: function (xhr, err) {
                alert("Error occured" + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });                   
        }
    });
</script>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upCustAd" runat="server">
    <Triggers>            
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSave" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddOtherLocation"
             DataTextField="Text"
             DataValueField="Value"
             runat="server"
             EnableViewState="true"
             CssClass="dropdownheight"
             ClientIDMode="Static">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        ------
        -----
        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" Text="Submit" runat="server" Width="100px" OnClick="CreateSomeThing" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**API Controller Code**

```
public class DeptController : ApiController
{
    public List<DeptInfo> GetEmployeeDept(string deptid)
    {
        .......
        return listofItems;
    }
}
```

When I submit the page, the dropdown always returns item count as 0 and selecteditem value as 0 in csharp codebehind page. Any issue in my approach?

Comment: Where are you trying to read the item count and selecteditem value?

Comment: as i mentioned above in the code behind (csharp) file.

Comment: You haven't posted your code behind.

Comment: @msm8bball the API controller code is the code behind.

Comment: Let's not call that a [code-behind](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/basics/code-behind/). There's a specific meaning for code behind and that is not it. Can you please explain exactly what you're trying to do in your question? It's unclear to me why you're using both an UpdatePanel and jQuery AJAX when using either of them alone could accomplish what I think you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your url seems to lack the extension of the page...

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        **url: 'path/GetEmployeeDept',**
        data: postData,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (Result) {
            $('#<%= ddOtherLocation.ClientID %>').empty();
            $('#<%= ddOtherAdLocation.ClientID %>').append($("<option value=0>Select</option>"));
            $.each(Result, function (key, value) {
                $('#<%= ddOtherLocation.ClientID %>').append($("<option></option>").val(value.DeptID).html(value.DeptName));
            });
        },
        error: function (xhr, err) {
            alert("Error occured" + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
```

should it be like   url: 'path/GetEmployeeDept.aspx'   ?

Comment: its not aspx page, its web API Controller.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to wrap your js with $(document).ready(function(){ ... your code ... }); Because looks like that DOM wasn't ready and your control with id ddOtherLocation.ClientID wasn't rendered.
2. The list items of DropDownList in server controls are stored in the ViewState and do not passed via postback. And in this case you have 0 items, because no items are stored in viewstate or was added to DropDownList during page load/init/etc.